# find 100 largest numbers from all the files present in different folders

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I recently had an interview where I was asked below question and it sounded pretty easy to me but then at the end it became tricky for me.

> There are lot of files in all the folders and their sub folders. Each
>   file will have lot of numbers in each line. Given a root folder, I need to find 100 largest
>   number from all those files. I came up with below solution:
>
> - Read all the files line by line.
> - Store each number in an array list.
> - Sort it in descending order.
> - Now get the first k numbers from the list.

But then interviewer asked me what will be the time complexity for this. I said since we are sorting it so it's gonna be O(nlogn) and then he asked how can we improve below program? Since you are storing everything in memory and then sorting it - what if you can't fit everything in memory?

I was confused then and couldn't figure out if there was any better/efficient way to solve the below problem. He wanted me to write the efficient code. Is there any better way to accomplish this?

Below is my original code I came up with:

```
  private static final List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int k = 100;
    List<Integer> numbers = findKLargest("/home/david");

    // sort in descending order
    Collections.sort(numbers, Collections.reverseOrder());
    List<Integer> kLargest = new ArrayList<>();
    int j = 0;
    // now iterate all the numbers and get the first k numbers from the list
    for (Integer num : numbers) {
      j++;
      kLargest.add(num);
      if (j == k) {
        break;
      }
    }
    // print the first k numbers
    System.out.println(kLargest);
  }

  /**
   * Read all the numbers from all the files and load it in array list
   * @param rootDirectory
   * @return
   */
  private static List<Integer> findKLargest(String rootDirectory) {
    if (rootDirectory == null || rootDirectory.isEmpty()) {
      return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    File file = new File(rootDirectory);
    for (File entry : file.listFiles()) {
      if (entry.isDirectory()) {
        numbers.addAll(findKLargest(entry.getName()));
      } else {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(entry))) {
          String line;
          while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(line));
          }
        } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
    return numbers;
  }
```

Comment: You only need to store 100 bigest number. if new number is smaller then smallest of them ignore it. if not remove smallest number in array and add new number. You may want to keep array sorted. Google for insertion sort.

Comment: It calls for a heap: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kth-largest-element-in-a-stream/

Comment: Another problem with your example is that there might be more numbers than will fit in memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of storing all **N** ( overall count of numbers in all files ) values and sorting them, you can store only 100 values - the largest ones in every moment.

Convenient and fast data structure for this task - [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) (usually based on [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap)). Create **min**-heap with 100 first values, then for every new value check whether it is larger than heap top. If yes - remove top, insert new item.

Space complexity is `O(K)`, time complexity is `O(NlogK)`, here `K=100`, so complexities might be evaluated as `O(1)` and `O(N)` (omitting constant term)

Python example to show how it works:

```
import heapq, random

pq = [random.randint(0, 20) for _ in range(5)]  #initial values
print(pq)
heapq.heapify(pq)                               #initial values ordered in heap
print(pq)
for i in range(5):
    r = random.randint(0, 20)    # add 5 more values
    if r > pq[0]:
        heapq.heappop(pq)
        heapq.heappush(pq, r)
    print(r, pq)

[17, 22, 10, 1, 15]   //initial values
[1, 15, 10, 22, 17]   //heapified, smallest is the left
29 [10, 15, 17, 22, 29]     //29 replaces 1
25 [15, 22, 17, 29, 25]     //25 replaces 10
14 [15, 22, 17, 29, 25]      //14 is too small
8 [15, 22, 17, 29, 25]       //8 is too small
21 [17, 21, 25, 29, 22]     //21 is in the club now
```

Comment: @MNo But Let's say in the queue at second-last it has 105 and at last it has 102 and then the next value is 110 then this case it should be replaced with the top and then move forward?

Comment: @Shivang Agarwal Yes. We remove minimum 102, insert 110, and 105 becomes new top

Comment: @MNo this will be handled by Binary heap or priority queue?

Comment: @Shivang Agarwal  Binary heap is a kind of priority queue  implementation (simple and popular), so saying "Binary heap" we assume "priority queue"

Comment: @MBo Here N is the number of files right? Also can you provide an example on how this will be implemented using "priority queue"?

Comment: N is overall count of numbers in all files

Comment: got it.. my solution is also O(nlogk) right, correct me if I am wrong? so what is the difference between mine and your solution?

Comment: What is length of your "numbers" list? It seems N for me, so sorting takes O(NlogN)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @MBo, the Java implementation is as below

Use [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

Create a min heap using priority queue of size 100

```
int MAX = 100;
PriorityQueue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(MAX);
```

Read the numbers from the files, insert and balance min-heap. Compare minValue in the min-heap with newValue. If bigger, then remove minValue and insert newValue.

```
public void balanceMinHeap(int newValue) {

    if(queue.size() < MAX) {
        queue.add(newValue);
        return;
    }

    if(queue.peek() < newValue) {
        queue.remove();
        queue.add(newValue);
    }

}
```

Now you can get 100 largest numbers from min-heap in Ascending-Order

```
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
        System.out.println(queue.remove());
    }
```

If you want the same 100 largest numbers in Descending-order, Just convert the same queue to max-Heap(i.e., Again a PriorityQueue )

```
Comparator<Integer> desendingOrder = new Comparator<Integer>() {
    public int compare(Integer x, Integer y) {
         return y - x;
     }
};

PriorityQueue<Integer> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(MAX, desendingOrder);
```

Or Just use in-build [Collections.reverseOrder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder())

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(MAX, Collections.reverseOrder());
```